# Get-VM cmdlet in PowerShell not displaying while in loop but displays after loop

Tags: powershell, while-loop, do-while

I am a bit of a rookie developer so bear with me. I am creating a small script to manage VMs in Hyper-V. I am using a switch statement within a do while loop for user selection. When I select "5", this is supposed to list the names of the current VMs within the terminal and sleep for 4 seconds. I am using the Get-VM cmdlet. When I select "5", it does not display anything. When I quit the program selecting "q" or "Q", it then displays the output after the program is finished running. Why could this be? I will provide my script below. Thanks!

```
function createVM {
    New-VM -Name TestVM -MemoryStartupBytes 4GB -BootDevice VHD -VHDPath .\VMs\Test.vhdx -Path .\VMData -Generation 2
    Write-Host "Creating VM..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 4
}

function deleteVM {
    Remove-VM -Name "TestVM" -Force
    Write-Host "Removing VM..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 4
}

function startVM() {
    Start-VM -Name TestVM
    Write-Host "Starting VM..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 4
}

function stopVM() {
    Stop-VM -Name TestVM -Force
    Write-Host "Stopping VM..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 4
}

function listVMs() {
    Write-Host "Here is a list of your VMs:`n"
    Get-VM | Select-Object -Property Name #This isn't working for some reason...
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 4
}

function settingsVM() {
    Write-Host "Here are some VM settings:`n"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}

do {
    Write-Host "`nHyper-V VM Manager`n"
    Write-Host "Enter Selection:`n"
    Write-Host "`t1 - Create a VM"
    Write-Host "`t2 - Delete a VM"
    Write-Host "`t3 - Start a VM"
    Write-Host "`t4 - Stop a VM"
    Write-Host "`t5 - List available VMs"
    Write-Host "`t6 - List Settings of a VM"

    $choice = Read-Host -Prompt "`nPlease enter a number (1-6) or 'Q/q' to quit the program"

    switch($choice) {
        '1' {
            clear
            createVM
            break
        }
        '2' {
            clear
            deleteVM
            break
        }
        '3' {
            clear
            startVM
            break
        }
        '4' {
            clear
            stopVM
            break
        }
        '5' {
            clear
            listVMs
            break
        }
        '6' {
            clear
            settingVM
            break
        } 
    }
} while($choice -ne 'Q' -or $choice -ne 'q')

Write-Host "Quitting program: returning to shell.`n"
Write-Host "Have a wonderful day!`n"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 4 
exit
```

I have tried using a regular elif statement to see if that solves the issue but it doesn't. I assume there is an issue within my loop.

Comment: Use `Get-VM | Select-Object -Property Name | Out-Host`.

Comment: In short: This is a _display_ problem: Your output results in implicit `Format-Table` formatting, which incurs a 300-msec. delay before output is rendered (to determine suitable column widths). By contrast, the `Read-Host` prompt prints _right away_, and therefore _before_ your tabular output prints to the display.The - suboptimal - workaround is to force _synchronous_ display output of the tabular data, with `Out-Host`. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: @mklement0 Using Out-Host fixed the issue. This makes sense! Thank you!!